# Find consecutive diphthongs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a list of addresses in my shops database. But clearly a lot of these are fake; they consist of strings like `dfdfdfsd@somewhere.com` and `qwsdrtghj@somewherelse.com`.

In other words: at least 5 dipthongs in a row. How can I search such a string in an `SQL query`? Basically: any `diphthong` followed by any `diphthong`, and that `5 times`.

Comment: if you can figure out exactly how to define a dipthong, then mysql's regex support will take care of the "5 times" business.

Comment: Make a regex matching a single consonant repeated at least 10 times. That will give you a match for 5 dipthongs.

Comment: but what if someone has really an address like that?

Comment: Just because you do not commonly see email addresses like these, does not mean that all email addresses like it are automatically invalid.

Comment: @MarcB: more accurate would be to say that I suspect an email address with 7 to 10 seemingly random consonants to be not from someone who serious to receive mail back from me: qqwqwqwqw or sdfsdfsdf or zxczxczxc or nmbjhnmmnbrth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doubling up on some of the consonants to determine a dipthong. For example:

```
dfdfdfsd
```

If I count `df`, `df`, `df` and `sd` as separate dipthongs, the total is four. So it looks like you may be overlapping:

```
dfdfdfsd
^df
 ^fd
  ^df
   ^fd
    ^df
     ^fs
      ^sd
```

That gives a total of 7 dipthongs.

I don't know how to match like that, so how about just checking if there are 5 (or more) consonants in a row? This will do it:

```
email RLIKE '[b-df-hj-np-twxz]{5,}'
```

If you don't want to treat `y` as a vowel, just add it into the string above. Put it between `x` and `z` for readability, or at the very least don't put it after one of the hyphens or you'll break the expression.

Likewise, if 6 (or 7 or 8) consonants in a row is the tipping point you're after, adjust the `5` in the expression above accordingly.

Comment: seems this is indeed the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome! Since this helped, could you kindly accept it as the answer? That will show other users with a similar question that the solution is workable. Also take heed of the comment from Anigel that five (or seven or ten) consonants in a row don't *automatically* make the email address false, though they certainly make it worth looking into.

Comment: My query is as follows (database is called rawlist, the table emailad and the field is email.
SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE `email` RLIKE '[^aeiouy]{5,}' returns all of the records in the database. 

when I change that to SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE `email` RLIKE '[%aeiouy]{5,}' it returns all addresses that have 5 vowels in a row ...

Comment: You got me on the right path: I changed it to:SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE `email` RLIKE '[%bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]{5,}' which does the trick. Is there a way to unselect vowels at the same time?

Comment: You're one step ahead of me :) I just now updated the answer and it's exactly the expression you have with one exception: the `%` means you're treating `%` as one of the characters you're looking for in the repetition. It has special behavior in `LIKE` but not in `RLIKE`.

Comment: I don't quite understand "unselect vowels"? Do you mean you want to get emails with a stream of five or more consecutive vowels in addition to those with five or more consecutive consonants? In that case you can use `email RLIKE '[b-df-hj-np-twxz]{5,}' OR email RLIKE '[aeiouy]{5,}'`. To omit rather than include, I'd use `NOT (email RLIKE '[b-df-hj-np-twxz]{5,}' OR email RLIKE '[aeiouy]{5,}')`.